# How to exclude this line in unix diff?

Tags: unix, diff

How can I exlude the following line in unix diff?

```
<xs:element attribute1="0" attribute2="return" attribute3="true" type="ax277:ResponseDataBean"/>
```

I need to exclude all cases where the number after 'ax' is different. For example, the following diff should be excluded:

File 1:

```
<xs:element attribute1="0" attribute2="return" attribute3="true" type="ax277:ResponseDataBean"/>
```

File 2:

```
<xs:element attribute1="0" attribute2="return" attribute3="true" type="ax111:ResponseDataBean"/>
```

I have tried:

diff -I 'type="ax^' file1 file2

But it is still displaying those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use XML tools for handling XML, because it's not going to be long before you find one of those files that was written with a line break in a place you don't expect it, making your line that you want to exclude no longer match a single-line pattern.

However, one way to do what you are asking would be to exclude those lines from the input that `diff` considers to begin with. Something along these lines, using `bash` process substitution:

```
diff <(grep -v 'type="ax[0-9]+:' file1) <(grep -v 'type="ax[0-9]+:' file2)
```